# "Dualizing" a particular Set-valued colimit

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $F:I\to \mathcal{C}$ be a diagram, and consider the colimit $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i),A),$$ where $A$ is a fixed object of $\mathcal{C}$.

Is it considered "legal" to write $\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i),A)=\hom_{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}(A,F(i))$, and use that to rewrite the above colimit as the limit $$\varprojlim_{k\in I^{\text{op}}}\hom_{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}(A^{\text{op}},F^{\text{op}}(k))\;\;?$$

I am just trying to get hold of what is allowed and how I can use the duality principle in this context. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confused about variance here.  First, the colimit $\varinjlim_{i\in I}\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i),A)$ doesn't make sense because $i\mapsto \hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i),A)$ is a contravariant functor from $I$ to $\mathtt{Set}$, not a covariant functor (remember that $\hom$ is contravariant in its first argument and covariant in its second argument).  So if you want to be computing a colimit in $\mathtt{Set}$, the index category would be $I^\text{op}$, not $I$.

Now let's look at what happens when we take opposites.  As you have said, $\hom_{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}(A^{\text{op}},F^{\text{op}}(k))$ is *the same set* as $\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(k),A)$.  But this means that the induced maps between these sets will still go in the same direction.  So the canonical functor from $I$ to $\mathtt{Set}$ sending $k$ to $\hom_{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}(A^{\text{op}},F^{\text{op}}(k))$ is still contravariant (you can also see this directly: $F^{\text{op}}$ is contravariant when considered as a functor from $I$ to $\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$, and $\hom$ is covariant in its second argument).  When you consider it as a covariant functor $I^\text{op}\to\mathtt{Set}$, this is literally the same functor as the functor $i\mapsto \hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i),A)$ we were considering before.  Since these are the same functor, we have $$\varinjlim_{i\in I^\text{op}}\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i),A)\cong \varinjlim_{k\in I^{\text{op}}}\hom_{\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}}(A^{\text{op}},F^{\text{op}}(k)).$$

Notice in particular that a colimit never turned into a limit.  The reason is that the difference between a colimit and a limit is the direction of the maps *in the category where your diagram lives*, which in this case is $\mathtt{Set}$.  You didn't change the direction of any maps in $\mathtt{Set}$, you just changed the directions of the maps in the category $\mathcal{C}$ of which you were taking hom-sets.

Comment: Dear Eric, thanks again for this. It took me some time to realise what was going wrong. The functor I care about is a limit, not a colimit, $\varprojlim_{i\in I}\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i),A)$. Now I am sure this makes sense. What I want is to turn this into a colimit. Please just correct me if I am wrong: the functor that gives the limit above is a functor $K: I\to \mathbf{Set}$. If I want to turn this into a colimit, I need to take the opposite of $K$, $K^{\text{op}}:I^{\text{op}}\to \mathbf{Set}^{\text{op}}$. Since (the underlying) $K^{\text{op}}(j)=K(j)$ for $j\in J^{\text{op}}$, the limit

Comment: above just becomes $\varinjlim_{k\in J^{\text{op}}}\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(D^{\text{op}}(k), A)$, but this time the colimit is computed in $\mathbf{Set}^{\text{op}}$.

Comment: $\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(D^{\text{op}}(k), A)$ needs, in reality (when actually computing the colimit) to be identified with the corresponding object of $\mathbf{Set}^{\text{op}}$.

Comment: Again, $F$ and $D$ are the same, sorry.

Comment: The limit $\varprojlim_{i\in I}\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i),A)$ still does not make sense if you intend it to be a limit in $\mathbf{Set}$, since this functor is still contravariant: you normally only talk about limits or colimits of covariant functors.  You can either take a limit of it as a functor $I^\text{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ or as a functor $I\to\mathbf{Set}^\text{op}$.  I'm not sure which you want.

Comment: If you have a functor $K:I\to\mathbf{Set}$, then it is true that the limit of $K$ is "the same" as the colimit of $K^\text{op}$ (that is, a limit cone of $K$ in $\mathbf{Set}$, when considered as a diagram in $\mathbf{Set}^\text{op}$ instead, is a colimit cocone of $K^\text{op}$).

Comment: Well I had not realized the $A$ makes so much difference. The limit I care about is in fact a (cofiltered) limit of representable functors $\varprojlim_{i\in I}\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(D(i),-)$. Does this still not make sense? This should be computed in $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathbf{Set}]$...

Comment: Your variances seem to be backwards.  Note that for any fixed $i$, $\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(D(i),-)$ is a covariant functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$, not contravariant, so your diagram isn't even a diagram of objects in $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathbf{Set}]$.

Comment: Oh God. Ok, thanks. I will rethink and try to work out all of this again. Thank you for your patience.